# Css Tricks, Diagonal Line

Tags: css, css-shapes

How could I re-create this using purely css/css3? Can your option please include a way to set border options, i.e. drop shadow styling.

[image]

EDIT

This is what I had:

```
.border_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top:15.5%; 
    margin-left:22%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Is that an arrow or a corner of something?

Comment: Hint: Use `transforms` and `skew`.

Comment: I have tried George and I have the diagonal line but not the flat. In which I used the skew option Harry. It's just a simple feature I want to put text inside / above for a heading Hendry. Thank you for taking your time to assist Mr_Green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try This: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dk334k9z/) (EDITED)

```css
body { margin: 50px; }
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
div:before, div:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

div:before { width: 400px; }
div:after {
    width: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 5px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <h1>My Text</h1>
</div>
```

*Vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity.*

Comment: When I click "Run code snippet", it just shows a white box.

Comment: Try this too - http://jsfiddle.net/6twsf8gs/

Comment: nice.. you also did round the borders. awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Transform: skew` css property.
Here is an example:

```
div {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    height: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd7f2hn1/1/)**

**[Updated fiddle for header inside](http://jsfiddle.net/bd7f2hn1/3/)** (*use pseudo class*)

Comment: But that is 90 degree. Can you make it smaller?

Comment: @HendryTanaka I didn't understand. what is 90 degree?

Comment: No problem, see my answer. I've got it.

Comment: Thank you for this, just one question. When I put a h1 tag (for example) inside this div it also angles my text. I'm trying to override it giving the h1 tag an id that contains skewX-0 but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Brock You could also add text inside your div. Please look at my updated answer. :)

Comment: @Brock Apply a `skew` in the opposite direction to the `<h1>` as well. http://jsfiddle.net/bd7f2hn1/2/